# How to integrate over segments using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns `t_b; t_e; x` were `[t_b, t_e)` denotes a period during which `x` resources where used. I want to compute a table were for each hour `h` I have amount of resources that where used during `[h, h+1)` period.

So far my only idea was to generate multiple rows from each input row for each hour (I use an extension of SQL with UDFs) and then simply `group by` by hour, but I'm afraid this may be too slow considering large amount of data at hand.

Say for example I have a table with two rows:

```
+-----+-----+---+
| t_b | t_e | x |
+-----+-----+---+
| 1   | 3.5 | a |
| 0.5 | 4   | b |
+-----+-----+---+
```

Then resulting table should be:

```
+---+-------------+
| h |      x      |
+---+-------------+
| 0 | 0*a + 0.5*b |
| 1 | 1*a + 1*b   |
| 2 | 1*a + 1*b   |
| 3 | 0.5*a + 1*b |
+---+-------------+
```

Comment: I am sure there is some relationship between the inputs and the result set you want.  It is entirely unclear to me.

Comment: What data types are the columns? From the description I would have expected them to be `time` columns, but your sample data only shows numbers

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, fixed example tables format, thank you!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, didn't think that type matters, first `t_b` and `t_e` are `time`, and `x` is `int`

Comment: Have a tally table of hours and join it to your table on interval intersection.

Comment: But `3.5` is not a valid value for a `time` column (and we still don't know which DBMS product you are using)

Comment: You need to show how you integrated those segments to create the resulting table.  Multiple people have said that your question is not clear.  You need to explain the columns- what datatype it holds, what it represents.  You get the resulting data by doing XYZ, etc. with the source table.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a trigger on insert into the stats table that also adds to the aggregate table (the per-hour sums).

If you also need to convert the existing data, you need to run over every row of your current table, split it into amounts/hours and add to the aggregate table.

Answer (score 0):

This is an sql-server example for all number columns

```
with h as (
  -- your hours tally here
  select top(24) row_number() over(order by (select null)) eoh from sys.all_objects
), myTable as (
  select 1 t_b, 3.5 t_e, 20 v  union all
  select  0.5, 4, 40
)
select eoh-1 h_starth 
   , sum(v * (case when t_e < eoh then t_e else eoh end - case when t_b > eoh-1 then t_b else eoh-1 end)) usage
from h
left join myTable t on t_e > eoh - 1 and eoh > t_b  -- [..) intresection with [..)
group by eoh;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca268794bf2bffe56c7d72666b6e7975)